# как в Report Builder добавить пустое значение?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый день!
Есть Список , через SQL запрос по переменным он выбирает подходящие значения из БД.  Как к списку значений добавить постоянную пустую запись, которая бы выбиралась по Default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить Union'ом к запросу эту самую "пустую запись" и задать ее значение как default.
Примерно так:

```
select -1 Id, 'Все' Name
union
select id, name from Items
```